# jQuery data attribute update not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following two links. When a user clicks Edit, I want to update the data-action attribute of the Cancel link to `cancel-edit`

```
<a class="btn btn-default js-edit" href="#" >Edit</a>

<a class="btn btn-default js-cancel" href="#" data-action="cancel-add">Cancel</a>
```

here is my script to achieve this:

```
$(".container").on('click', '.js-edit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $('a.js-cancel').data('action', 'cancel-edit');

    console.log($('a.js-cancel').data('action')); 

});
```

In the console, the above results are as expected i.e. console displays `cancel-edit`

When I click the Cancel link after the above action, the below script doesn't work. When I view the result in console, it still outputs `cancel-add`?

```
$(".container").on('click', '.js-cancel', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var a = $(this);

    if (a.attr("data-action") == 'cancel-edit') {
       // do something
    }

    console.log(a.attr("data-action"));
});
```

Comment: when updating data attributes with .data() it does not update the markup, so you will need to check the data using `a.data('action') == 'cancel-edit'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because using `data()` inside of jQuery will not update the `data-*` attribute in the DOM, but rather in the object itself.

Simply call `data()` again inside your click handler:

```
if( a.data('action') == 'cancel-edit' ) 
{
       // do something
} 
else 
{
       // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use .prop() instead of .attr() beacause .prop() gives you the latest value,

Comment: That's not the case, since both `prop()` and `attr()` deal with the DOM, but not directly with `data()`... https://jsfiddle.net/fqtmg86s/

Comment: Ok i guess i take the question in wrong way